# Estimate of sum of elements of a partition of an interval

Tags: proof-explanation, riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

I'm reading the proof of the [sewing lemma](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/esaim-probability-and-statistics/article/abs/rough-paths-via-sewing-lemma/EBA18185F3F15940F9C8BB92A858AF4C) and i'm not able to proof a quite straightforward result that is implicetly used in the paper.

Given an interval $\left[s,t\right]$ and a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of such interval we define the mesh size as $|\mathcal{P}|=\sup_\limits{[u,v] \in \mathcal{P}} \left|u-v \right|$.

Given $\beta>1$ we have that
$$
\sum_\limits{[u,v] \in \mathcal{P}} |u-v|^\beta \le \left|t-s\right| \ \ \left|\mathcal{P}\right|^{\beta-1}
$$
The result is used to prove that an operator is a Riemann type limit. As far as I know this result holds only if $\beta>1$, so i guess that $\sum_\limits{[u,v] \in \mathcal{P}} |u-v|^\beta$ is not bounded by $|\mathcal{P}|^\beta$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the closed interval $[u,v]\in \mathcal{P}$ and  $\beta > 1$ we have $|u-v| \leqslant |\mathcal{P}|$ and, hence,  $|u-v|^{\beta-1} \leqslant |\mathcal{P}|^{\beta-1}$.

Thus,

$$\sum_\limits{[u,v] \in \mathcal{P}} |u-v|^\beta =\sum_\limits{[u,v] \in \mathcal{P}} |u-v|^{\beta-1} |u-v|\leqslant |\mathcal{P}|^{\beta-1}\sum_\limits{[u,v] \in \mathcal{P}}  |u-v| = |\mathcal{P}|^{\beta-1}|t-s|$$

The last equality follows because, by definition of a partition, the subintervals are non-overlapping and cover the interval $[s,t]$. Whence,

$$\sum_\limits{[u,v] \in \mathcal{P}}  |u-v|= t-s = |s-t|$$